# geom_point() rainbow colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on the diamonds data set. I am trying to plot carats x price, with the color representing clarity. I get a beautiful color palette, but not the one I want. It looks more like a gradient, and I want the rainbow, with each clarity having a unique color (easier for such a dense data plot, I think).

When I have created my basic plot, everything works. Once I try to add in `scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow())` and any variants, I get an error.

```
#what works
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=clarity)) + 
  geom_point()

#what doesn't...
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=clarity)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors=rainbow(7))
```

I would like to see colors but instead, I get the feedback that discrete value is supplied to a continuous scale. How would I fix this?

Comment: Rainbow colour scales are, in general, a bad idea. They are not colour-blind friendly and have perceptual problems. See #endrainbow on twitter for more

Comment: @RichardTelford you're absolutely right, and this is a great consideration. I'm just playing around with the data set for my own purposes right now. Is gray scale more colour-blind friendly for when I someday present data? :)

Comment: Have a look at viridis colour scales - available within ggplot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scale_colour_gradientn()` creates a colour gradient for continuous values. If you instead want discrete values to have distinct colours use `scale_colour_manual()`. Further, colours are assigned using `values =` :

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, colour = clarity)) + 
geom_point() +
scale_colour_manual(values = rainbow(8))
```

[image]